# Achieving Billiard ball simulation with box2d on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, box2d

using this properties:

```
b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef;
    ballShapeDef.shape = &circle;
    ballShapeDef.density = 1.0f;
    ballBodyDef.linearDamping = 1.0f;
    ballBodyDef.bullet = YES;
    ballShapeDef.friction = 1.0f;
    ballShapeDef.restitution = 0.7f;
    ballBodyDef.angularDamping = 3;
```

Im trying to simulate a pool ball in a world set to gravity (0,0) and hitting
the ball like this:

```
- (void) applyShot:(float) ang {

    float vx = 10 * cosf(ang);
    float vy = 10 * sinf(ang);

    b2Vec2 velVec = _whiteBall->GetLinearVelocity();
    velVec.x += (vx * 10);
    velVec.y += (vy * 10);

    _whiteBall->SetLinearVelocity(velVec);

}
```

The ball really behaves a bit unrealistically because it "glides" too much
slowly on the table after a stronger shot, not stopping.

My table borders are static walls, is that enough?

Regards
Mirza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By directly setting the linear velocity, the billiard ball isn't participating in the physics simulation. Instead, you will want to use

```
_whiteBall->ApplyForce(velVec, _whiteBall->GetWorldCenter());
```

or

```
_whiteBall->ApplyLinearImpulse(velVec, _whiteBall->GetWorldCenter());
```

I highly recommend the iforce2d tutorials on [linear movement](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/forces) and [constant speed](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/constant-speed) to really get a feel for the *correct* way(s) to interact with Box2D bodies.